# Нужна помощь в устранении ошибок

Tags: python

Дали задание на дз с HyperSkill: устранить все ошибки в коде так, чтобы он стал рабочим.

> If the function is called in the following way: print_list([1, '2', 3,
> '4']), then the output should be like this:
>
> ```
> 2
> 0
> 4
> ```

Код:

```
def print_list(some_list):

    while i < range(len(some_list)):
        if some_list[i] % 2 == 0:
            print(some_list[i])
        if some_list[i] % 3 = 0:
            print(some_list[i] % 3)
        i += 1
```

Я так понимаю, что нужно использовать цикл for после определения функции и исправить 3 == 0. Больше идей нет. Буду рада любой помощи.

Comment: что вам мешает проверить свои предположения?

Comment: Нужно условие задачи, чтобы разобраться.

Answer (score 2):

вы уже задавали этот вопрос вчера

еще раз повторю:

1. вы используете НЕ СРАВНЕНИЕ, а ПРИСВАИВАНИЕ

   ```
    if some_list[i] % 3 = 0:
        print(some_list[i] % 3)
   ```

вместо двойного `==` используете одинарное `=`

2. в случае кратности элемента 6ти, у вас будет выполняться сразу 2 условия и будет выводиться сразу 2 элемента

   ```
    if some_list[i] % 2 == 0:
        print(some_list[i])
    if some_list[i] % 3 == 0:
        print(some_list[i] % 3)
   ```

если этого не требуется, то надо использовать `elif`:

```
    if some_list[i] % 2 == 0:
        print(some_list[i])
    elif some_list[i] % 3 == 0:
        print(some_list[i] % 3)
```

3. вы работаете с числами, но в списке в вашем примере вы передаете и строки:

   ```
    print_list([1, '2', 3, '4']),
   ```

поэтому, в зависимости от задачи, предположу, что надо перевести сначала строки в числа (любым способом)

```
    some_list_new = list(map(int, some_list))
```

или

```
    if int(some_list[i] % 2) == 0:
        print(some_list[i])
    elif int(some_list[i] % 3) == 0:
        print(some_list[i] % 3)
```

правда если передавать будут чистые строки (не числа в виде строки), то программа будет падать и надо использовать или `try` или предварительную проверку на число

или не рассматривать не числа (не знаю условия задачи, точно сказать не могу), например

```
    if isinstance(some_list[i], int) and some_list[i] % 2 == 0:
        print(some_list[i])
    elif isinstance(some_list[i], int) and some_list[i] % 3 == 0:
        print(some_list[i] % 3)
```